# send activation email after registration of new extranet user

Tags: membership-provider

we create  a custom registration page to register extra-net user in our sitecore application ,but our customer request activation email to activate account . 
 the problem is there is no activation filed in the sitecore core db , there is any solution to achieve this requirement ?

```
string userName = string.Concat(firstName, lastName);
            userName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, userName);
            string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 3);
            try
            {
                if (!User.Exists(userName))
                {
                    Membership.CreateUser(userName, newPassword, email);

}
```

Comment: Are you kidding me with this many tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MembershipUser has a property(IsApproved) to disable the user.

So the code will be

```
            string userName = string.Concat(firstName, lastName);
            userName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, userName);
            string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 3);
            try
            {
                if (!User.Exists(userName))
                {
                  var createduser =  Membership.CreateUser(userName, newPassword, email);
                  createduser.IsApproved = false;
                  Membership.UpdateUser(createduser);
            }
```

This disables the created user. 
On the mail activation, the code will be

```
          if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(userName))
            {
                var createduser=  Membership.GetUser(userName);
                createduser.IsApproved = true;
                Membership.UpdateUser(createduser);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this in a Sitecore setup, but the CreateUser method does have an [overloaded version like this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership.createuser?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Security_Membership_CreateUser_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Object_System_Web_Security_MembershipCreateStatus__):

```
public static System.Web.Security.MembershipUser CreateUser (string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status);
```

Important here is the "**isApproved**" boolean. If you set that to false, the user is created but should not be able to login. Once activated, you could set this value to true.